# Is there a model change listener mechanism in android

Tags: java, android

I am designing a android user interface for a sports app.
One of the features of the app is that the text of buttons and menu items changes as 
the game state progresses. So you go from setup game -> start first half -> half time -> second half -> game over etc. The buttons and the menu item text change to indicate the next valid actions in the app.

Now so far I am doing that by watching a global var of the state and basically checking this in the various onCreate, onResume methods. at least for the buttons anyway. Not sure about menu items and how to make them dynamic.

Now I figure there must be a better way to do this in android ? In swing you might have a modelchangelistener and you could register as a listener of that in your view. Does something similar exist in android ? Also I know in Java you can do the Observer pattern but I was looking for something built into android. I imagine this scenario is fairly common.

But if there is not then NO YOU HAVE TO DO IT YOURSELF is an acceptable response to my question too.

Thanks in advance. 
Frank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

You have to implement your own Listener and then you can use a `selector` in the XML file you create later on. Just like when you use it with `Buttons` : `android:state_pressed="true"`

Edit: However, I really suggest you don't spend time at all on this task as that can be accomplished in any other simpler way.

Comment: So you are saying that you would not advise using the selectors because it would get too complex ? Is the simpler way you are thinking off mayby through observer/observer pattern or some other mechanism in code ?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have anything in particular like an `Observer`/`Observable` - even though you are free to use those in Android as well.

The question is: should you use `Observer`/`Observable`-classes, or not? Some say no, because it requires you to override an `update`-method which takes an `Object` parameter. This is not OO-friendly. Others, love it.

Those against it, suggest you write your own `Observer` classes, and register those Observers manually. Each `Observable` should then iterate through a list of `Observer` instances to say:

"Hey! Here's an update."

Comment: Hello Etienne I think we have crossed the bridge already with Observer/Observable in that we all ready use it in another part of the system. So we might as well use it in this instance too. I understand what you are saying that you could probably build a better more OO version by implementing the observer pattern yourself but I prefer to use pre-existing components rather than do my own for reasons of speed and quality. So I take your answer to mean android doesn't provide a mechanism but Observer/Observable is one way to implement this scheme. As such you have provided a valid answer.

Comment: `java.util.Observable` is not very suitable for Android, because it is not an interface, but a concrete class that you need to extend, which conflicts with the usual Android need to derive from a specific superclass such as Adapter, Activity, View or similar. I would define my own Observer/Observable interfaces.